# value sent as list, but received as string. (TypeError: string indices must be integers)

Tags: python

good evening,
I have a function in lambda that returns a list, the value is returned correctly but as a string, and I cannot access a specific item. What would be the correct way to reach the value, I will greatly appreciate your support.

function Lambda is:
...

```
respuesta_servicio=[{"bool_respuesta":1,"resultado":response.text,"error":respuestaJson}]
return list(respuesta_servicio)
```

the return value on the call.

```
[{"bool_respuesta": 1, "resultado": "{\"errors\":\"error 21\",\"codigo\":21}", "error": "error red"}]
```

type value is:

```
<class str>
```

When I call the function from another .py file, I verify that it comes as string. generating an error.

```
respuestaServ=[]
respuestaServ= envialambda.invoke_lambda_envia(bytes(json_result, 'utf8'))

os.system("echo Respuesta-python : '{}'".format( str(respuestaServ) ))
```

value is:

```
 [{"bool_respuesta": 1, "resultado": "{\"errors\":\"error 21\",\"codigo\":21}", "error": "error red"}]

os.system("echo Guia typo-python : '{}'".format( type(respuestaServ) ))
```

value is:

```
<class str>
```

when i want to access a specific item, the error is generated. what is the correct form of accder.

```
os.system("echo *******************: '{}'".format( respuestaServ[0]['bool_respuesta'] ))
```

errors:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

the lambda code is :
import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):

respuesta_servicio=[]
respuesta_servicio=[{"bool_respuesta":1,"resultado":response.text,"error":respuestaJson}]

return list(respuesta_servicio)

Comment: You'll need to provide code that can be executed start to finish; the individual parts look fine (I think) but clearly something is happening in between that we're not seeing.  For example, the return value you showed definitely looks like a list; how are you determining that it's a string?

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
I show the type of the variable.
os.system ("echo Guide typo-python: '{}'". format (type (serviceResponse)))

Comment: Please, Add the lambda function

Comment: import json
import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
        respuesta_servicio=[]
        respuesta_servicio=[{"bool_respuesta":1,"resultado":response.text,"error":respuestaJson}]
        return list(respuesta_servicio)

Comment: hello the lambda code, it is small and I return the list manually, copy it in the initial request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in that your `envialambda.invoke_lambda_envia(bytes(json_result, 'utf8'))` return `string` rather then `list` of `dicts`.

One approach could be this;Just after :

```
respuestaServ=[]
respuestaServ= envialambda.invoke_lambda_envia(bytes(json_result, 'utf8'))
```

You can use literal_eval:

```
import ast
respuestaServ=ast.literal_eval(respuestaServ)
```

Which will transform the string into list:

```
print(respuestaServ[0]['bool_respuesta'])
```

Output: `1`

Warning([per docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html?highlight=ast%20literal_eval#ast.literal_eval)) It is possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler.

*edit:*

```
import json
aa = '[{"bool_respuesta": 1, "resultado": "ganado", "error": "errores"}]'
print(json.loads(aa)[0]['bool_respuesta']) # int 1
```

A third way, if you know that the value that you want is after the first ":" and before the first "," inside the list:

```
aa = '[{"bool_respuesta": 1, "resultado": "ganado", "error": "errores"}]'
cc = [c.split(", ") for c in aa.split(":")]

print(cc[1][0]) # output string 1
print(int(cc[1][0])) # output int 1
```

Comment: thanks, import ast was solved.

Do you recommend that I handle it this way, or that I receive the string and convert it to json and work it as json ??, I was left with the doubt.

Comment: You're welcome! If there's a chance that the dict will be too big, I would use the json formatting (added to answer, check after edit) or the third-choice.